# React Native Throw Network Error when Fetch .NET CORE 3 webApi

Tags: android, react-native, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to fetch a WEB API create in .NET CORE but the return is always Network Error, i'm using axios to fetch api.
I'm using the URL with my ip adress(https://MY_IP:1258/)(just like when i create Node api's) and already tries CORS solution(not work)

I had already tried to fetch PokeApi and it's OK.

[Thats the implementation on axios, simple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sV2i.png)

[Api get on my real android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M34x8.png)

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3M4D.png)

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code. Post a question with clarity and details describing your issue - Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting

Answer (score 0):

In the .net core project right click on properties and go to the debug tab. In the APP URL field you should have something like http://192.168.1.2:80